# TSQL Rank() With Sequence

Tags: sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have Following tsql statements

```
Select *,RowNum = Rank() OVER(Order by paging.parentID) from paging
```

Its Result is Like this

```
ParentID         RowNum
11                  1
11                  1
11                  1
23                  4
23                  4
23                  4
```

But what I want is...

```
ParentID         RowNum
11                  1
11                  1
11                  1
23                  2
23                  2
23                  2
```

In other words for every unique parentID I want rownumber to be SAME and whenever parentID  changes I want RowNum to jump to next number (dont skip any #'s).

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `DENSE_RANK` instead of `RANK`.

[SQL Fiddle with demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/4b363/1).

Comment: oh WOW, I did not know about it.